# How to access to attribute of a class from other classes?

Tags: java, jsp

I have designed a website in which I need to have access to user's profile, so I have a user class that keeps the profile information of users, such as name,username,etc to avoid of retrieving them from database every time.

Whats the best way to access to this information from other classes?
My idea is to make them all static to access to the attributes using class's name is there any other option?

Comment: Are you using an database? If not you could use cookies

Comment: how about making them session scoped ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal solution is to store the user data within a `database` and have your other classes retrieve said data via a `data access object` [(DAO)](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/dataaccessobjectdesignpattern.html). Any alternatives to this will most likely clutter your existing architecture and create security holes.

Store the user data in a user bean, keep the bean stored in the user's [session](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/manage-sessions.html), and then upload the bean to a database for future access.

Comment: thanks for your response how about if it was not website application? how to upload the bean object in database!!!!???

Comment: It does not have to be a website in-order to use DAOs or POJOS (aka user bean).

Comment: I mean how to upload the bean into database?

Comment: INSERT INTO user_table( username, fname, lname ) VALUES (userClass.getUserName, userClass.getFname, ....     get the picture?

Answer (score 4):

For a website, my idea is

- Once you retrieve data for user class that keeps the profile
  information of users from database, save  to **session**.
- You can retreive data of user from session whenever you wants from
  other classes.
- In the case if you want to update user data to database, you also
  need to update user in session object.

By using session, you can avoid every time going to and from database.

The use of session in jsp can be found in http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/UseSessionJsp.htm

Comment: thanks for your response how about if it was not website application?

Comment: Your question said that "I have designed a website" so so..:D

Comment: Yes it is website but I am wondering whats the alternative for session if it was not website. another thing is that how can I upload the session that keeps the class object into database?

Comment: If it is not web application, my idea is using Singleton pattern.http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/using-the-singleton-pattern-in-java/449 for user object as I want only one instance to user object.